# issue with relative addresses, when include an PHP page that points to many external JSs

Tags: php, javascript, include

I have an PHP page that points to many external JavaScript files (let's name it *myJS.php*).

i want to include it in many different PHP pages, in different folders.

The problem is that all the JS files of *myJS.php* get relative addresses when i include *myJS.php* in pages in different folders.

For example: if there is something like **src="main/calendar.js"** in *myJS.php*, when i include *myJS.php* in a PHP page in different folder, it changes to **src="subfolder1/subfolder2/main/calendar.js"**

any solution for this problem?

thanks in advance.

Comment: I wonder if something like [chdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) would be useful in some way here.

Comment: @jordojuice — It wouldn't, since the browser is interpreting the URIs, not the PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably complete solution looks like this:

```
define('IS_WINDOWS', (stripos(PHP_OS,'WIN') === 0));

$webserver_root = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
if (IS_WINDOWS) {
 //convert windows path separators
 $webserver_root = str_replace("\\","/",$webserver_root); 
}
$web_root = substr($webserver_root, strlen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']));
// Ensure web_root starts with a path separator
if (preg_match("/^[^\/]/",$web_root)) {
 $web_root = "/".$web_root;
}       

$host = ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? "https://" : "http://") . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$path = $host.$web_root.'/bla/bla';
```

if you're working on localhost at the moment (on a windows machine), first check PHP_OS and then create the absolute path and use it for external JSs.

Comment: Be careful when generating URLs from physical paths on your server. They do not always match.
Most webservers allow to map a request for a given URL to a file at a completely different physical location.

An example of this is the mod_rewrite module of the apache webserver.

Comment: A URL `/includes/js/myscript.js` could be remapped by the webserver to `/includes/scanned/minified/merged/myscript.js`.

Answer (score 2):

You could generate an absolute url:

```
$url = ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? "https://" : "http://") . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/mypath/myfile.bla';
```

You may want to var_dump or r_print the $_SERVER variable to see what properties are available and usefull to build an absolute url.
But as @Quentin mentioned - don't make it too hard, you might get away by starting your path with a slash, which references the root of your site, as in `/mypathfromroot/myfile.bla` as opposed to `myrelativepath/myfile.bla`.

Comment: Erik, thanks for your answer,
i added some more lines and came to a solution,
i will post my final solution as an answer, so other people might find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

- Absolute URIs
- Absolute paths (i.e. URIs relative to the site root (starting with `/`))
- Prefixing all the URLs with `$base` which you either compute from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` or hard code.